# Unit testing BackgroundService using WebApplicationFactory<Startup>

Tags: c#

Is it possible to initialize and unit test BackgroundService.ExecuteAsync() using IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory> ?

I have `x-unit tests`

```
public class SomeTests
        : IClassFixture<ApplicationFactory>
        { }
```

and `ApplicationFactory.cs`

```
 public class ApplicationFactory
            : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>, IDisposable
            { }
```

and `startup.cs`

```
services.AddHostedService<ProcessBackgroundTaskQueueService>();
```

However, when I try to

```
var service = this.factory.Resolve<ProcessBackgroundTaskQueueService>();
```

I get an error

```
System.InvalidOperationException
No service for type '....ProcessBackgroundTaskQueueService' has been registered.
```

How would I go about unit testing it using `WebApplicationFactory<Startup>`?

TIA!